# How do I navigate the MiniBufExplorer without going into the MiniBufExplorer window?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, buffer, vim

How do I navigate the MiniBufExplorer without going into the MiniBufExplorer window?

In lines 170-174 of `minibufexpl.vim`:

```
"               To enable the optional mapping of <C-TAB> and <C-S-TAB> to a 
"               function that will bring up the next or previous buffer in the
"               current window, you can put the following into your .vimrc:
"
"                 let g:miniBufExplMapCTabSwitchBufs = 1
```

I added that to my `.vimrc`, restarted a blank Vim, then did the following commands to bring up multiple buffers (and consequently, the MiniBufExplorer):

```
:e somefile
:e someotherfile
```

Now, with my cursor inside the file window (not the MiniBufExplorer window), I try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to no effect. Something I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is most likely a conflict with snipMate, which I believe you have since you mention the tab mapping works in select mode. I tried to do it manually `map <C-Tab> :bn<cr>`,
and it did not work either. I now use `map <C-P> :bp<cr>` and `map <C-N> :bn<cr>` to navigate through buffers, and I suppose other mappings would work just as well as long as there is no conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Minibuf explorer shortcuts (may require additional configuration):

[C-TAB] and [C-S-TAB] - move to next and prev buffers

Vim regular buffer shortcuts:

:bn and :bp - move to next and prev buffers
:b# - move to buffer of number #

:h :buffers - for additional help

Answer (score 0):

Did you leave the `"` at the beginning of the `let` line? If so, it's commented out, and will not work. Otherwise, you may have a mapping conflict between plugins. The `:map` command will list current mappings.

It's easier to deal with mappings if you install [headlights](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Headlights) though.

Comment: When I use `:map`, the only `<Tab>` mapping is one with an `s` prefix. It probably means that it takes effect only in Select Mode, correct? Will this still conflict the the MiniBufExpl settings?

Comment: @Kit It shouldn't conflict. Though it does mean you probably did comment the let line. Uncomment it and check is the easiest thing to do.